# ¿Por que no se redibuja correctamente este Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un formulario y quiero que al presionar el botón de envío este se redibuje y pase de decir "Ingresar" a "Espere".

Para esto utilizo un `StatefullWidget` con la propiedad `isLoading` que cambia al ser presionado el botón con un `setState` de false a true. El texto del botón se renderiza según el valor del booleano `isLoading`, sin embargo al presionar el botón este no se redibuja correctamente y sigue mostrando el texto "Ingresar".

```
    class _LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<_LoginForm> createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<_LoginForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool isLoading = false;

    return Container(
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
            ),

//Botón en cuestion
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed:(){
              setState(() {
                isLoading=true; //setState donde debería redibuujarse el botón
              });
              } ,
              child:Container(
                child:Text(isLoading ? 'Espere' : 'Ingresar', style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),//Texto que se renderiza según isLoading, pero que no se redibuja como debería
              ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas cometiendo un error, la variable `isLoading` debe ir fuera del método `build`.

```
    class _LoginFormState extends State<_LoginForm> {
     bool isLoading = false;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
            ),
            //Botón en cuestion
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed:(){
              setState(() {
                isLoading=true; 
              });
              } ,
              child:Container(
                child:Text(isLoading ? 'Espere' : 'Ingresar', 
             style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
              ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```